# Cmake cleaning all files

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

As the title suggests, I was playing around with CMake and I accidentally built the binaries in my System 32 folder ~facepalm~. I want to delete all the files CMake has ever created from my system. How do I do that?

As you can see, I'm new to all this so please be as detailed as possible!

In my command prompt, I tried cmake --build  --target clean. Didn't work.

Comment: Build your project in some other folder, then note which files and subfolders are created in that folder. Those files and subfolders you could remove from the system32 folder.

Comment: I'm surprised how this even happened. You ran CMake as administrator?

Comment: Tsyvarev, thank you! Yes I did that in the end. They really should build a functionality to delete all Cmake made files though.
Starball, yes I ran the cmd as admin because I was having other issues building the project. It was a compatibility issue so I thought this would fix it.